# ValueError in > comparison

Tags: python, numpy

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Feb 29 14:56:52 2020

@author: 12064
"""
import numpy as np

k = 0
### size of function
n = 5
######## creating test function
A = np.random.randn(n,n)
B = np.transpose(A)
C = np.matmul(B,A)    # A,B,C working
gradf = np.gradient(C, axis=0)
def myFcn(x):
    return np.dot(C, x)
def gradientmyFcn(x):
    return np.dot(gradf, x)

######## C = Q Rick defines
######## define the point
xT = np.random.randn((n))
x = xT.reshape((n,1))
print('myFcn(x)')
###### define gradient

#####initial alpha, c

###### define descent direction, and set of descent directions
p = np.zeros((n,1))
pT = np.zeros((1,n))
pT = gradientmyFcn(x)
pT.reshape(1,n)
p = np.transpose(pT)
p.reshape(n,1)
#P = {p[0]:p[k]}
#p[0] = gradf initial descent direction
def ArmijoLineSearch(alpha):
    tao = .1
    alpha = 1
    c = 1.e-4
    backtrack_factor = .5
    gradfx = gradientmyFcn(x)
    gradfx = gradfx
    gradTx = np.transpose(gradfx)
    xk1 = (x + (alpha*p))
    check_step = np.dot(gradfx, p) 
    LessThan = myFcn(x) + (c*alpha)*check_step
    if myFcn(xk1) > LessThan:
        alpha = backtrack_factor * alpha
    else:
        if (np.transpose(mygradientFcn(xk1)) @ p) < tao * np.dot(np.transpose(gradfx), p):
            print("weak curvature condition does not hold")
        else:
            return alpha
ArmijoLineSearch(alpha)
```

The error occurs on this line: `if myFcn(xk1) > LessThan:`

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I'm struggling to understand this error since it seems to be taking the numpy arrays of random numbers (at least initially random) and trying to operate with booleans. What is the problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: try to print just before the `if` the values of each element from the condition i.e. `myFcn(xk1), LessThan` just to see what are you trying to compare...

Comment: Doing a `>` test on a numpy array produces a numpy array of booleans.  An `if` only works with 1 boolean; there's not implied loop in an `if`.  Describe **exactly** what you expect `if myFcn(xk1) > LessThan:` to be doing.